# Is possible to create a cron-job on a as400 system (IBM) in order to update/insert large quantity of data on online server?

Tags: web-services, ibm-midrange

I was looking here if is possible to insert/update a large quantity of rows from an as400 system.

I have a website stored on another server online and that website must be updated with the new stocks for each article. But this data only exists in the as400 system.

I would like to be the as400 system linking the web-server instead of the web-server link to as400 for security reasons.

A better system would be to update/insert everytime a change has been made in the as400, but if this is not possible it could be making an update every 3 hours in order to mantain consistency between the 2 servers.

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice to have more information like how the network is setup. Can the IBM i see the web server? Can the web server see the IBM i? What languages are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to push data from one database to another... why?  If you're pushing _all_ your data to the 'webserver', you may overload it.  Otherwise, your iSeries is going to have to wait for database connections to request data - it's not psychic, after all.  A viable alternative would be to restrict access to only one view (doable trivially), which provides the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

You can attach a database trigger to your stock table that pushes the key fields to a [data queue](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/obj2.htm?resultof=%22%64%61%74%61%22%20%22%71%75%65%75%65%22%20) anytime an insert, update or delete is performed.  You can then process the data queue to send the updates to the web site using an HTTP POST or other means.

---

- [IBM Redbook: Stored Procedures, Triggers, and User-Defined Functions
  on DB2 Universal Database for
  iSeries](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246503.html)
- [IBM i 7.1 Information Center: Data Queue APIs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fobj2.htm)
- [Scott Klement's RPG IV Sockets Tutorial](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/index.html)

Comment: thanks (: can you help me out with some tutorials on the internet?

Comment: @Totty Updated with some additional references.

Comment: @Totty I'm not sure about the "(:" reference.  Is that supposed to be a happy or a sad face?  Is there anything else I can provide to help you along with your task?