# How to make a simple API from AS400+DB2 IBM in order to sync data with an external website+mysql?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, ibm-midrange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is possible to create a cron-job on a as400 system (IBM) in order to update/insert large quantity of data on online server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224307/is-possible-to-create-a-cron-job-on-a-as400-system-ibm-in-order-to-update-inse)

I have an AS400 system using DB2 on IBM Series and I would need to sync this data with another database that is hosted on another domain for a website.

We have all the articles on the AS400 system and I would like to update the stock in the website. It should be the most accurate possible and automatic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPG can make use of JDBC. So you can [write a RPG/Java](http://www.scottklement.com/presentations/#EXTERNALDB) program that can sync with the MySQL.